# The Entity Framework 6.2 doesn`t support json data type on DB first from MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, json, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are using Entity Framework 6.2 with DB first from MySql DB. Started to use json type there, but can`t map it to EF. In edmx file I found the error, what sounds like:

```
<!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6005: The data type 'json' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'customer_3rd_party_aws' in the table 'def.myquestworld_2.customer_3rd_party' was excluded.
warning 6005: The data type 'json' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'customer_3rd_party_phonegap' in the table 'def.myquestworld_2.customer_3rd_party' was excluded.
warning 6005: The data type 'json' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'customer_3rd_party_ios' in the table 'def.myquestworld_2.customer_3rd_party' was excluded.
```

As I know EF 6 should support json type, and 6.2 it is tha last version for current time. Am I wrong? How can I solve the issue?

Comment: I think this link is helpful: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/EF-JSON-Support.html

Comment: Looks like only DevArt connector is supporting json data type, but it is not free. Is it possible to solve the issue not buying any product?